# require gem issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have installed google api client with the following code and it installed successfuly.

```
gem install google-api-client
```

I am using rails 3.0.3 so i also included the above line bundler and ran bundle install which went successfully.

I have also rvm installed. And created a gemset.

And when I run the following command in the terminal:

```
gem environment | grep INSTALLATION | awk '{print $4}'
```

It gives me the following result

```
/home/jamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

When i try to execute the following code in scintilla outside the project directory. It gives me an error.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'google/api_client'
```

ERROR:

```
usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- google/api_client (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
```

What is the main reason of this kind of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible chances are your editor does not loading the specific `gemset` in which you install the gem.

Please provide output of `gem list google-api-client -d` in your questions. So that I can figure it out exactly what is going one.

EDIT:
Another issue which usually occurs are the dual installation of ruby. When we do have a system level installation and a rvm installation, many editor got confused in it. They load up original system installed ruby which do have prefixes like `1.8.7`, `1.9.1`and available in `/usr/share/bin/`. Where was you had installed the gem in rvm profile. To overcome this problem you must run your code from terminal after choosing the right `gemset`

Answer (score 0):

I had that `google/api_client (LoadError)` message but, it concerned another Google gem.

```
gem 'google_drive', '~> 0.3.10'
gem 'google-api-client'
```

I just removed the `, '~> 0.3.10'` part in case of it was a compatibility problem. That did the trick:

```
Using google-api-client 0.7.1 (was 0.9.4)
Installing google_drive 1.0.6 (was 0.3.11)
```